# i3 core performance problems

Tags: 10.10, xorg, performance, intel-graphics

I just tried to play Quake3 (QuakeLive) on a new laptop with an i3 core integrated gpu, running Ubuntu 10.10. Strangely, the performance was terrible. I'm running on intel driver, which seems to load correctly. I know it's not a high-end system, but I got used to Q3 being fairly playable on 3yo built-in i850GM with single core cpu, which was obviously much worse.

After switching to i3, I get barely 5fps, even if I use very low resolutions (640x480 and similar).

What could affect the performance that much? What should I look for? There doesn't seem to be anything obvious in the Xorg logs, or my xsessionerrors.

Comment: I tried this both with disabled and enabled compiz. With disabled, it's a bit faster, but still practically unusable (looks like still < 10fps).

Comment: Tested also openarena. That runs at >60fps with no problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And the answer seems to be:

```
\r_ignorefastpath 0
```

Now I get really smooth graphics all the time.

Comment: Nice, thanks for sharing the solution. Speaking of that I have an Urban Terror question I need to make.